# using xpath fetch top level list of nodes having specific attribute

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Please provide me X-path expression for the below scenario.

The Element Tag name are not constant they can vary , also the hierarchy may vary as in the above case the path attribute is present at level 1, there might be a case it is not present at level 1 but below that.

Expected Result : NodeList nodeList = { a,z}; list should not contain the b or y nodes

```
<root>
   <a path="a">
        <b path="b"></b>
   </a>
   <z path="z">
        <y path="y"></y>
   </z>
</root>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. When tag names can vary, how to distinguish whether to select the element? Not by hierarchy either, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply as this:

```
/root/*[@path]
```

**Update**

If the root name is not a constant:

```
/*/*[@path]
```

Comment: Element name can be any thing not specific root

Comment: This work but the path attribute is not present at level 2 and its present at level 3 then it does not work, it would be helpful if there is any possibile xpath for this condition. thanks a lot

Comment: Hum... I must understand the requirements first. Must be included the nodes over the first level (`b` and `y` in your example)? In the question you stated explicitly **no**.

Answer (score 0):

First [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) is a good XPath tutorial.

To search into the XML just follow this syntax :

```
String query = "tag[@param= '" + param.getName() + "']";
            log.debug("Xpath query = {}", query);
            XPathExpression<Element> xpe = XPathFactory.instance().compile(query, Filters.element());
            for (Element urle : xpe.evaluate(packages)) {
                urle.doSmth();
            }
```

If you want to select something anywhere in the document, use `//`.
For example `//x` selects all tags named x